# UPDATE statement resulting in process that is automatically killed

Tags: mysql

I want to add the ID values to table_1 by matching on three fields with table_2:

```
update table_1 t1
join table_2 t2 on t1.col_1 = t2.col_1 
and t1.col_2 = t2.col_2
and t1.col_3 = t2.col_3
set t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Table_1 has about 3 million rows and table_2 has about 300,000. The three fields are indexed in table_1, and there is a unique index on the same fields in table_2. When I run this script the process is killed automatically after about 1,200 seconds, and the State and Info fields in SHOW PROCESSLIST show NULL.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: I don't know anything about MySql but would 1,200 seconds correspond to a timeout setting?

Comment: is t1.ID a unique id or primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Check how much memory you have while this is running. The size of the join may be too much for your OS to bear. Also run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see where the waiting is.

As a workaround you could write a script to loop over the 300,000 rows

```
foreach t2 rows as row
UPDATE t1
SET t1.id = t2.id
WHERE ...
```

It won't take too long.